# Why am I getting cannot convert from 'MimeKit.MimeMessage' to 'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mimekit

I am using MimeKit for my SMTP, but I keep getting that error, when I call client.send. Below is my code:

```
      var mailman = new MimeMessage();


    var client = new SmtpClient();

   //SMTP Credentials here.

    //  Create a new email object
    mailman.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(message.FromAddress, message.FromAddress));
    mailman.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(message.ToAddress, message.ToAddress));
    mailman.Subject = message.MailSubject;

    var builder = new BodyBuilder();

    builder.HtmlBody = string.Format(message.Content);

    mailman.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();

    client.Send(mailman);
```

once I call client.Send(Mailman), I get the error. Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you thought of casting mailman to System.Net.Mail.MailMessage at client.Send()? As per their documentation http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Creating-Messages.htm, see at end, that you can cast it.

Comment: To convert back `MimeKit.MimeMessage` to `MailMessage`, you need a workaround as provided [here](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/issues/140). Basically you need to assign every properties from `MailMessage` class manually from the `MimeKit` instance.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Why not use MailKit? `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` is deprecated anyway.

Answer (score 3):

`System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` takes a `MailMessage` as a parameter ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.send?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Mail_SmtpClient_Send_System_Net_Mail_MailMessage_)), therefor I assume that you are trying to use this `SmtpClient` implementation, which is not compatible with MimeKit. You'll have to add the [MailKit NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/) to your project and

```
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
```

to your source file in order to use the `SmtpClient` implementation from MailKit.